# Printing consecutive numbers, can't modify function

Tags: javascript, function, loops

I've been in some technical interviews, this one got me frustrated as I can't modify the existent function and need to print 5 consecutive numbers (Number: 1, Number: 2, Number: 3....) plus the Promise

```
console.log('Logging Num 1');
const printNumber = (number) => {
  return new Promise((resolve) => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      console.log(`Number: ${number}`);
      resolve();
    }, Math.floor(Math.random() * 10));
  });
};

printNumber(1);
printNumber(2);
```

This was the hint, I remembered this one for looping through elements

```
for(let i = 1; i <= 5; i+= 1)
```

But how can I add this in the code without modifying the function? Yes I got nervous and confused.

Comment: do you mean `for (let i = 1; i <= 5; i+= 1) { printNumber(i); }` ?

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to do this

```js
const syncLog = async (x) => {
    for(let i = 0; i < x; i++){
        await printNumber(i)
    }
}

syncLog(5)

>> Number: 0
>> Number: 1
>> Number: 2
>> Number: 3
>> Number: 4
```